# Same parameters passed in every spring batch job run

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I just switched from REST endpoint triggered spring batch job to a command line job run method.
I removed the controller class which had the `JobLauncher`.
Now I am trying to run the job with the following command:

> `java -Dspring.batch.job.names="SOME JOBNAME" -jar somejar.jar`

I see a `run.id` and `time` job parameters being passed by default in the `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS` table.
I didn't see these params being passed by default when I used to trigger the job with the REST endpoint launcher approach.

And the same value of both these params is being passed in each job-run.
`run.id=1` and `time=1612515999654`.
And as expected, it gives me the following `JobInstanceAlreadyComplete` exception.

My job bean is something like this:

```
@Bean
public Job job() throws Exception {
    return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("SOME JOBNAME")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(someStep())
            .build();
}
```

I have this `createJobRespository()` method overridden, by extending the `DefaultBatchConfigurer` class which I use because my metadata tables are in a different schema in sql server db than the default `dbo` schema.

```
@Override
protected JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
    JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
    factory.setTablePrefix("someSchema" + ".BATCH_");
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return factory.getObject();
}
```

When I remove the `createJobRespository()` method and thus use the batch metadata tables in default `dbo` schema, only `run.id` is passed by default and incremented as expected. No `time` param is passed by default in this case.

My question is:

1. Why this `time` and `run.id` job parameters are being passed by default when I trigger the job using command line?
2. And why is the value for both the parameters being passed the same every time I run the job? Even if I am using the `new RunIdIncrementer()`
3. How is the `createJobRespository()` method creating the difference?

Comment: run.id will be incrementing you can check in table select * from BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS bjep order by 1 desc . These are default parameters.

Answer (score 0):

> Why this time and run.id job parameters are being passed by default when I trigger the job using command line?

Based on your job definition, only the `run.id` parameter should be added to job parameters from the `RunIdIncrementer`. I don't see from what you shared where this `time` parameter would come from.

> And why is the value for both the parameters being passed the same every time I run the job? Even if I am using the new RunIdIncrementer()

That should not be the case. With a `RunIdIncrementer`, every new run should generate a new `run.id`. If this is not the case, please provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue.

> How is the createJobRespository() method creating the difference?

I don't see how this is related to the issue. The job repository does not influence job parameters in any way.